# v-for not aligning content properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this bit of vue code executing that is supposed to loop and generate `<img>` with `<p>` tags where the `<p>` tag is aligned below each image.

Each image is then aligned to fill a grid from the top as seen in the image below:
[image: What I am trying to achieve]
My current code:

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in ingredients">
    <div class="row full-padding">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">{{index}}</div>
        <div v-bind:id="index + 'BUTTON'" class="col-lg-6 hoverable text-right" v-on:click="toggleShow(index)">[-]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row full-padding" v-bind:id="index">
        <span v-if="!ingredient[2] && !ingredient[1]" v-for="(ingredient, ingdex) in category">
            <img class="ing-img hoverable" v-bind:src="ingredient[3]" v-on:click="toggleIngredient(ingredient)" v-bind:name="ingredient[0]" width="20%"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

however, when I changed the code to add a `<p>{{ingredient[0]}}</p>` to display the name of each ingredient under the image all the items misalign!  How do I fix this and why is this happening?

What is happening:
[image: What is happening]

The broken code:

```
<div v-for="(category, index) in ingredients">
    <div class="row full-padding">
        <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">{{index}}</div>
        <div v-bind:id="index + 'BUTTON'" class="col-lg-6 hoverable text-right" v-on:click="toggleShow(index)">[-]</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row full-padding" v-bind:id="index">
        <span v-if="!ingredient[2] && !ingredient[1]" v-for="(ingredient, ingdex) in category">
            <img class="ing-img hoverable" v-bind:src="ingredient[3]" v-on:click="toggleIngredient(ingredient)" v-bind:name="ingredient[0]" width="20%"/>
            <!-- This is the changed bit here -->
            <p>{{ingredient[0]}}</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverable:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ing-img {
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.rec-img {
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.full-padding {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.customBorder {
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #FF4136;
}

#header {
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.ing-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this misalignment only occurs when I add the line:
`<p>{{ingredient[0]}}</p>`

Comment: Show your CSS please

Comment: You are also using `col-lg-6 ` in the CSS (takes half screen)

Comment: Sorry forgot css! https://hastebin.com/mopurebona.css

Comment: It'd also be helpful if we could get your data set over which you are looping (`ingredients`)